# Reddit Bot which replies to comments

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

Using the PRAW library, the reddit bot replies to the post title in a subthread when the given keyword is mentioned. I would like to change so it replies when mentioned within the comments in a sub, not the post.

```html
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

    import praw

    QUESTIONS = ["!hello"]
    REPLY_TEMPLATE = "world"


    def main():
        reddit = praw.Reddit(
            user_agent="xxx",
            client_id="xxx",
            client_secret="xxx",
            username="xxx",
            password="xxx",
        )

        subreddit = reddit.subreddit("sandboxtest")
        for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
            process_submission(submission)


    def process_submission(submission):
        # Ignore titles with more than 10 words as they probably are not simple
        # questions.
        if len(submission.title.split()) > 15:
            return

        normalized_title = submission.title.lower()
        for question_phrase in QUESTIONS:
            if question_phrase in normalized_title:
                url_title = quote_plus(submission.title)
                reply_text = REPLY_TEMPLATE.format(url_title)
                print("Replying to: {}".format(submission.title))
                submission.reply(reply_text)
                # A reply has been made so do not attempt to match other phrases.
                break


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to process comments change:

```
for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
  process_submission(submission)
```

to:

```
for comment in subreddit.stream.comments():
  process_comment(comment)

# def process_comment you have to write yourself
```

---

If you want to process comments and submissions do:

```
while True:
  for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions(pause_after=-1):
    process_submission(submission)
  for commentin subreddit.stream.comments(pause_after=-1):
    process_comment(comment)
```

---

an example of `process_comment()`:

```
def process_comment(comment):
  for question_phrase in QUESTIONS:
    if question_phrase in comment.body.lower():
      comment.reply("Hello")
```